# Sudden crash after render finished - no image, no logs

Tags: rendering

In 2.8 I have a project which suddenly does not render single frames at full resolution. The set evolved over a few weeks with no problems.

Now if I render a still at target resolution it will finish the render and than totally crash out. No log nor message nor image is written, render window and main window just disappear.

No system overload, 50 % memory, I already reduced threads. Also checked temp file path, permissions, everything. I compared all render settings with an older file version and disabled composing flag. Updated to 2.81a.

Render at 80% works. I tried to hide everything in the scene at full resolution: crash. The task manager shows a spike in GPU 3d at the moment of crash.

Is there a hidden process between rendering and writing the final image?

And no, I can't share the project but will try to answer any question.

Thanks,
Carolo

Comment: Hello and welcome :). It's just a guess, but lowering render tile size helps for me in similar cases. Or switching to CPU rendering.

Comment: Thanks Jachym,
already cpu only, tilesize no problem.

My own question (process between rendering and writing) led to the solution.

Actually, there was a "SurfaceDrawing-Something" in the scene.
Must have been a mistyped sculpting action.
Whatever it is, it invokes a postprocessing which obviously is very hungry at some 30k resolution.

Comment: Congrats on solving it :). Please post your solution as an answer, so others can find it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

My own question (process between rendering and writing) led to the solution. Actually, there was a "SurfaceDrawing-Something" in the scene. Must have been a mistyped sculpting action. Whatever it is, it invokes a postprocessing which obviously is very hungry at some 30k resolution.

So watch out for strange elements in the outliner!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the file it is hard to advice. In this situation you should make sure the GPU drivers are up to date and installed correctly. Update them just in case. But why? - you may ask, since it worked fine. Because of automatic updates. They may fail. You may even try previous version of drivers if you know that an update really did happen in between when it worked and now when it doesn't.

You should try to diagnose the reason this is happening, by seeing what parts of the scene work and what don't. I would try just copying everything in the scene to a new file first see if that helps. Then I would start deleting and disabling stuff to see what I need to remove for it to work. I would start with suspicious features first. Maybe you are using experimental feature set, or multiple CUDA devices?.. Denoising, passes, render layers, compositing, some new features that might have bugs?.. Try disabling stuff and see if it helps(not necessarily as a solution, but  to find out what causes it). See if it happens rendering with GPU, CPU or both. Reducing tile size may be a good idea. Then there is also a possibility that some data in your file somehow got corrupted. It could be any data, so start deleting data blocks. You can delete half of the scene and if it start working fine you know it's in the deleted half and so on and so on. Once you know the reason why this is happening it will be easier to know what your options are.

It may also be a hardware issue. Is the CPU/GPU/RAM overclocked? They might become unstable.

Once you know more about it you should also report it as a bug. If it crashes, it's always a bug.

Comment: Thanks Martinas,
i have everything on the safe side, even the computer is completely offline.
Also tried the copy to new scene.
The solution is in my comment above.

Comment: Oh, you solved it already. Did not see it while writing. It would be awesome if you could find the time to describe the solution in detail in an answer for others with similar issue to find.